# Why do I have to use this.canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object)

I ran into a problem with the following code:

```
var BuildMiniMap = function(camera, mapSize, width){

    this.camera = camera;
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    this.mapSize = mapSize;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = Math.floor(mapSize[1]/(mapSize[0]/width));

    alert(canvas);
}

var miniMap = new BuildMiniMap(camera, [800, 600], 200);
```

Running it in a webpage will lead to an error in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: canvas is not defined
```

And I have to use `this.canvas` instead. This only happens with `canvas` property, but not any other property. Does anyone know the reason and can provide an explanation? Thanks!

Comment: `but not any other property` Try `height`

Comment: Yeah, I found it out...sorry about my silliness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other three properties, `camera`,`mapSize` and `width` are all defined as function arguments so are available within the function scope.  `canvas` is not a function argument and is not defined inside the function so it doesn't exist within the scope.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to distinguish between variables and properties. There are only three [local] *variables* in your constructor function, namely the parameters `camera`, `mapSize`, and `width`.

`canvas`, `height` etc. are *properties* of your instance, which you assign some values to by using the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).